# Using Java Scanner class ,how do I get the most recent number which comes after specific String?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have text log  files which follow this format:

> 18:27:08.231 [main] DEBUG sample_client - This is a DEBUG  message,
>   line 39 Location 7 18:27:09.231 [main] DEBUG sample_client - This is
>   anr DEBUG  message, line 39 Location 17 18:27:10.231 [main] DEBUG
>   sample_client - This is a DEBUG  message, line 56 Location 23

I would like to obtain the most recent integer, that comes after the String "Location" - here it is 23.

The following is my Scanner class so far :

```
 import org.apache.logging.log4j.flume; */
// import org.slf4j.Logger;
// import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ScannerTest {  /* BEGINBRAC */



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        int mostRecentLocation = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner ("LogbackTutorialError.txt");         

        while (scanner.hasNextLine() ) {

            final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();

            if(lineFromFile.contains("Location")){

                System.out.print("the location is " + mostRecentLocation );
            }

        }


    }

}// end class ScannerTest
```

How do I go about getting the most recent number after Location ?

Comment: Is that the only content of file? Are we sure that `Location 23` will always be in last line?

Comment: @Pshemo - no, log file changes

Comment: So could you change your example to reflect that? Maybe add some lines which will show us how your log file can look like. For now assuming that log can be long one of more interesting options could be reading file backwards line by line and checking if line ends with `Location xxx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something with [`String.substring(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) to remove everything from `Location` on. Something like,

```
if (lineFromFile.startsWith("Location")) {
    int mostRecentLocation = Integer.parseInt(lineFromFile
            .substring(1 + "Location".length()).trim());
    System.out.println("the location is " + mostRecentLocation);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code shows how to create it.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ScannerTest {  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException { 
        int mostRecentLocation = 0;
        File newFile = new File("LogbackTutorialError.log");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (newFile);         
        int result = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine() ) {
            String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();       
            Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(lineFromFile);
            if(lineScanner.findInLine("Location") != null){
              result = lineScanner.nextInt() ;
              mostRecentLocation = result;           
            }

        }
        System.out.println(" The location is  : " + result );


    }

}// end class ScannerTest
```